# jquery mouseover / show-hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a script for showing div on mouseover.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("a.prikaziDiv").hover(

                function() {
                    var $sibling = $(this).siblings('div.prikazano').show(); // get the sibling div and show it
                    $('div.prikazano').not($sibling).hide(); // hide the other divs
                }, function() {
                    $(this).siblings('div.prikazano').delay(999).fadeOut(0);; // get the sibling div and hide it after .333 seconds
                });

            });

</script>

<a class="prikaziDiv" href="#">SHOW</a><div class="prikazano" style="display:none;">aa</div>
```

Its working, but when i hover "SHOW" link, i come with cursor on that div, but it dissapear. I don't want to div dissapear.

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are hovering the anchor, and the div appears, and when you hover the div, it dissapears because you are no longer hovering over the anchor, so the mouseleave part of hover() triggers. You can either put the div within the anchor, or use a timeout, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer;
    $("a.prikaziDiv").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            var $sibling = $(this).siblings('div.prikazano').show();
            $('div.prikazano').not($sibling).hide();
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            var self = this;
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                $(self).siblings('div.prikazano').fadeOut(1);
            }, 999);
        }
    });

    $('div.prikazano').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(this).delay(999).fadeOut(1);
        }
    })
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XXjga/2/)

Answer (score 0):

use mosueenter instead of hover.

http://jsfiddle.net/kkobold/y8hb9/

Comment: whend o you want it to hide?

Comment: and is it better to be done with mouseleave? http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/ or not? Thank you!!